# Cannot update project using Subversion in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, svn, svn-checkout

I am trying to update my project using svn (right click on the project name -> Subversion -> Update Directory). The next error appears: "No versioned directories to update were found".
Also, when I try to checkout the project, i get the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ithLk.png)

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is rather generic, it basically means svn client could not connect. Could be caused by misconfigured proxy server settings, errors in servers configuration file or firewall.

Check if it works in the command line in the first place. Also, check the [IDE logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085), the issue could be caused by something else

Comment: Thank you! I solved it eventually... Indeed it was a proxy problem.